# JanusGraph .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

Hey Can anyone help me figure out how I can connect to remote JanusGraph server hosting several graphs and query a specific graph (by graph name) using C# JanusGraph.net ?

I can connect to the server but I can't query a specific graph.

```
var c = JanusGraph.Net.JanusGraphClientBuilder.BuildClientForServer(server).Create();
var connection = new DriverRemoteConnection(c);
var g = Traversal().WithRemote(connection);
```

How we can implement ConfiguredGraphFactory.create("graphName") or ConfiguredGraphFactory.open("graphName") in JanusGrapgh.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DriverRemoteConnection` can take another parameter in addition to the `GremlinClient` argument:

```
var c = JanusGraph.Net.JanusGraphClientBuilder.BuildClientForServer(server).Create();
var connection = new DriverRemoteConnection(c, "graphTraversalSourceName");
var g = Traversal().WithRemote(connection);
```

Note that remote traversals do not bind against `Graph` instances. They bind against a `GraphTraversalSource`, so you must change "graphTraversalSourceName" to the name of one of those configured objects on the server. When you don't supply this argument, it just defaults to "g" by the way. Also, please note that .NET API documentation can be found [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/dotnetdocs/3.4.6/api/Gremlin.Net.Driver.Remote.DriverRemoteConnection.html#Gremlin_Net_Driver_Remote_DriverRemoteConnection__ctor_Gremlin_Net_Driver_IGremlinClient_System_String_).