# Simple Gremlin.NET - How query graph by name

Tags: c#, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

How we can implement something like this in Gremlin.net

**To create a config template:**

```
map = new HashMap<String, Object>()
map.put("storage.backend", "cql")
map.put("storage.hostname", "xxxxx")
map.put("index.search.backend", "elasticsearch");
map.put("index.search.hostname", "xxxxx-elastic");
map.put("index.search.elasticsearch.transport-scheme", "http");
ConfiguredGraphFactory.createTemplateConfiguration(new MapConfiguration(map))
```

**To create a new named graph:**

```
ConfiguredGraphFactory.create("a") //Assumes config template is set up
```

#### To open and access a graph and traversal for use

```
graph = ConfiguredGraphFactory.open("a")
g = graph.traversal()
g.V()........ ready for use
```

Comment: is your question answered by https://stackoverflow.com/q/61393535/1831717 ?

Comment: Yes  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430542/simple-gremlin-net-how-query-graph-by-name